# PGP Decryption with plain text key only.

Tags: pgp, decryption

I have been given a gpg file and a plain text key. I was expecting an .asc file.
What would the syntax be to decrypt this file with a plain text key.
For example:

```
pgp --decrypt filename.gpg keyname
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried that command?

Answer (score 0):

From your description symmetric encryption was used IMO. In this case you can pass the passphrase to gpg on command line like this:

> cat keyname | gpg --passphrase-fd=0 filename.gpg

or

> echo "plain text key" | gpg --passphrase-fd=0 filename.gpg

Comment: You can just use `gpg --passphrase-file keyname filename.gpg` instead.